# Looking for assistance with MVC Authentication with .Net Maui App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, maui

Currently I have an application that is running asp.net MVC 5 utilizing Owin.IAppBuilder for authentication. This was the standard authentication method when building mvc applications. This auth method connects to a SQL database and uses the standard aspNetUsers table method.

I am looking to start building a .net Maui mobile app. This .net Maui app I would like to allow existing and future users of my MVC 5 application to authenticate.

I researched many options but unsure the best method to start implementing. Does anyone have suggestions on what Path I should take?

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion and generally off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own web service for authentication, you can use WebAuthenticator to achieve it.

For more information, please refer to: [Web Authenticator | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios)